# Populating a model field based on another model field from a different model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to populate "balance" in Transaction model based on "beginning_balance" in the Accounts model, but I'm getting the following error message:

> save() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'pk'

What am I doing wrong. Thank you.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Accounts(models.Model):
    account_nickname = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    beginning_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_nickname


class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    account_nickname = models.ForeignKey(Accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    balance = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, request, pk):
        get_beginning_balance = Accounts.objects.get(id=pk)
        self.balance = get_beginning_balance
        super().save(request, pk, *args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_nickname
```

> This the correct query. I realized I wasn't pulling the right data.

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_beginning_balance = 
 Accounts.objects.filter(account_nickname=self.account_nickname).values("beginning_balance")
        self.balance = get_beginning_balance
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Show your views.py.

Comment: I'm not rendering the output yet, so I don't have anything on the view.py. I'm looking at Django Administration for the result by manually entering records.

Comment: @MrHobbit When you invoke save(), do you pass the `request` and `pk`?

Comment: Thank you everyone. your comments made me realized I wasn't pulling the right query. it should have been:
```
get_beginning_balance = Accounts.objects.filter(account_nickname=self.account_nickname).values("beginning_balance")```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do in your save function in the Transaction model would best be done in your views.py file. You could get the Accounts model based on the pk id that was passed in your url as an int:pk with something like this:

```
def view_name(request,pk):
```

You could then get your desired Accounts object with a [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404). I would then create your account balance with Transactions.objects.create(*your arguments*). It should end up looking something like this:

```
def view_name(request,pk):
acc=get_object_or_404(Accounts, account_nickname=sample_account_nickname)
Transaction.objects.create(transaction_date=sample_date, 
account_nickname=acc, 
amount=sample_amount)
```

Good luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding Django Model save function with wrong number of arguments.

If you want to set something in Django Admin you should override proper method, in ModelAdmin in this case [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) would be appropriate

> The save_model method is given the HttpRequest, a model instance, a
> ModelForm instance, and a boolean value based on whether it is adding
> or changing the object. Overriding this method allows doing pre- or
> post-save operations. Call super().save_model() to save the object
> using Model.save().